# AS3 Object appears onClick where the mouse clicks on the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, click, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I want in actionscript to place an object in my library onto the stage where I clicked. Seems easy? Right? TOTALLY BLANKING. any help would be awesome :)
my code thus far is:

```
package code {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var redBox: Box = new Box(mouseX, mouseY);

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickEvent);
    }
    public function mouseClickEvent(e:MouseEvent):void {
        addChild(redBox);
    }
}

}
```

that is the main and then the box code is:

```
package code {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Box extends MovieClip{

    public function Box(myX:Number, myY:Number) {
        // constructor code
        myX = x;
        myY = y;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this :

```
package code {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var redBox: Box = new Box();

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickEvent);
    }
    public function mouseClickEvent(e:MouseEvent):void {
        redBox.x = stage.mouseX;
        redBox.y = stage.mouseY;
        addChild(redBox);

    }
}

}
```